# Implement API REST to an existing Django app

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm looking for a good tutorial that illustrates that how can I Implement API REST to an existing Django app.

Because I tried the official docs and other tutorials, and I'm still confusing, I'm unable to build an API for each function that I have.
Is there any easy way to implement that?
Thanks,

Comment: Could you give a minimal example on your views (in `views.py)`? How are you implementing them now? If you are returning an html page and using `context`, you could just use [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) and  handle the rest with JavaScript.

Comment: @Countour-Integral can you explain more please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) package in order to develop your RESTful API.

Comment: yes I know, it's so confusing, is there any easy way to implement rest in an existing project?

Comment: I would suggest you to use a new app in your existing project where you can implement the serializers of your existing models, the views according to your needs and the urls for your views. The serializers allow you to validate the web service's payload and create an model record, (partially) updat/delete an exising model record. The views include the `authentication_classes` , `pemissions_classes` if you want to authorize the request or perform a custom permission check, perform the query in the db etc. For each view, you must define a url in the app's urls.py.